# Install Windows 11 on an Unsupported PC. Rufus secure boot settings?

Tags: rufus

Making bootable Windows 11 installer.
I have old Dell 7010 optiplex (Intel Core i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz)
with UEFI/ secureboot, **but not TMP 2.0**.

What happens to secureboot in bios or windows, if i tick option.?

Rufus option:

[ x ] remove requirement for secure boot and TMP 2.0

---

thanks for the replies

I forgot to mention that the CPU isn't supported either, Rufus doesn't have that option yet.
The point is to do a clean installation.
So using the windows 10 registry is not possible.

One possibility might have is to modify Windows 11 bootable media.
But there don't seem to be any instructions for that anywhere.

Comment: Give it a try. Nothing will explode.

Comment: @Gantendo, however, if he succeeds, the system may be unusable. Of course, one could then install Linux.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik If you drink a lot Win11 is pretty decent.

Comment: Under those conditions, Windows 3.1 is not too bad, either.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to secureboot in bios or windows, if i tick option.?

Nothing. The option only removes the requirement checks done by the installer.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to Use Rufus to Bypass TPM and Secure Boot Requirements
in Windows 11 installation.

You need to enable these three options :

- Remove requirement for 4GB+ RAM, Secure Boot, and TPM 2.0
- Remove requirement for an online Microsoft account
- Disable data collection (Skip privacy questions)

With these requirements removed, the Windows 11 installer will not
insist on them.

[image]

For more information see the article
[How to Use Rufus to Bypass TPM and Secure Boot Requirements in Windows 11](https://www.makeuseof.com/rufus-bypass-tpm-secure-boot-requirements-windows-11/).

Answer (score 0):

Rufus, or any third-party tool for that matter, isn't required to bypass the installer requirements; Rufus does makes it slightly more convenient *(it auto-performs the steps listed under Windows, minus temp space modification)*, but this can be done while booted to the installer in WinPE or after the Install USB is created, but before rebooting to the installer:

---

### WinPE

**CLI:**

1. Boot Install USB → Open a terminal: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
2. ```powershell
   ::# Disable TPM Req:
       Reg Add HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig /v BypassTPMCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1

   ::# Disable SecureBoot Req:
       Reg Add HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig /v BypassSecureBootCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1
   ```
3. Continue through installer's GUI

**GUI:**

1. Boot Install USB → Open a terminal: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> → `regedit` → <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Navigate to: `HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig`

   1. Disable TPM Req: 
       Right-click on `LabConfig` → *New* → *DWORD (32-bit) Value* 
       *Value Name:* `BypassTPMCheck` 
       *Value Data:* `1`
   2. Disable Secure Boot Req: 
       Right-click on `LabConfig` → *New* → *DWORD (32-bit) Value* 
       *Value Name:* `BypassSecureBootCheck` 
       *Value Data:* `1`
3. Continue through installer's GUI

---

### Windows

**Install USB:**

1. Open Admin terminal: <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* `powershell` → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+OK
2. ```powershell
   # Create working directory:
     MkDir "C:\mount"

   # Get correct image index (Windows Setup is usually #2):
     Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"<InstallUSB>:\sources\boot.wim"

   # Mount WinPE Windows Setup WIM:
     Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"<InstallUSB>:\sources\boot.wim" /Index:2 /MountDir:"C:\mount"

     # Load WinPE SYSTEM hive:
       Reg Load HKLM\WinPE "C:\mount\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM"

     # Disable TPM Req:
       Reg Add HKLM\WinPE\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig /v BypassTPMCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1

     # Disable SecureBoot Req:
       Reg Add HKLM\WinPE\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig /v BypassSecureBootCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1

     # Unload Hive
       Reg Unload HKLM\WinPE

   # Set WinPE default temp space to 512MB:
     Dism /Set-ScratchSpace:512 /Image:"C:\mount"

   # Unmount:
     Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"C:\mount" /Commit

   # Cleanup:
     RmDir /s /q "C:\mount"
   ```
3. Boot Install USB